# Vue firing requests one after another

Tags: vue.js, vue-resource

I have two functions. I would like to fire a function - wait until `firstFunction()` has ended and then fire `secondFunction()`. But I **don't want to** do this as a callback.

```
firstFunction() {
        this.$http.post(
          `url1`,
            data1,
          { channel: 'default' },
          { headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' } }
        ).then(response => {
            console.log(response)
        });
},
secondFunction() {
       this.$http.post(
          `url2`,
            data2,
          { channel: 'default' },
          { headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' } }
        ).then(response => {
            console.log(response)
        });
},
finalFunction() {
    this.firstFunction() 
    this.secondFunction()
}
```

Comment: within your `firstFunction` return the http post call: `return this.$http.post(...`. That will return the `Promise`, so you can then do this in your `finalFunction`: `this.firstFunction().then(() => this.secondFunction())`

Comment: probably what you need is like [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uvceyzob/2/)

Comment: @thanksd Your answer worked for me and was the easiest one, thanks!